# "Cannot borrow immutable content as mutable" when moving a closure into a thread

Tags: rust

In Rust, I want to specify a callback (e.g. a closure) to be called by a worker thread when something interesting happens. What would be the correct type signature for the callback?

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
use std::thread;

fn spawner(f: Box<FnMut()->()+Send>) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        f();
    })
}


fn main() {
    let cb = || {
        println!("callback");
    };
    spawner(Box::new(cb)).join().unwrap();
}
```

> ```
> src/main.rs:5:9: 5:10 error: cannot borrow immutable `Box` content
> `*f` as mutable
>
> src/main.rs:5         f();
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutability in Rust is inherited: because the variable `f` holding the box is immutable, the contents of the box are also immutable. An immutable `FnMut` closure cannot be called (`FnMut` requires the ability to mutate its environment).

Solution: make the variable `f` mutable:

`fn spawner(mut f: Box<FnMut()->()+Send>) -> thread::JoinHandle<()>`

Answer (score 1):

The Rust compiler is not allowing you to move the immutable argument `f` into the closure. Changing it to mutable (adding `mut` before the variable) the compiler will stop complaining and you will get the desired behaviour.

```
use std::thread;

fn spawner(mut f: Box<FnMut()->()+Send>) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::spawn(move || {
        f();
    })
}


fn main() {
    let cb = || {
        println!("callback");
    };
    spawner(Box::new(cb)).join().unwrap();
}
```